# How to implement our own custom sign up form with passport google o auth?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, passport.js

I am using react and node for my current project. I am using google o auth 2.0 for authentication. After the callback process is finished with google, I want to redirect the user to my custom route where I will show them some form. The user should fill additional information like addresses, phone number etc and only after that I want to save them in my database. The form is going to be shown by redux-form.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:keys.googleClientId,
    clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
}, async (req,accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done)=>{
    done(null,profile.id);
}))

app.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'] }))

app.get('/auth/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }),(req,res)=>{
        // req.user recieves a google id.

    })
```

As you can see in the above code after the callback is finished, the req recieves the user google id. My question is how can I show the form to my user during this process(using react), preserve the googleID until  the user fills the form and submit the form with the googleID.